# SQLite gives wrong output based on date column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * from matches WHERE home_player == 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' OR away_player == 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' AND strftime('%Y', date(match_date)) == '2019' AND competition = '%'
```

When I run this query in SQLite I get the following output:

[image]

Why are these values returned? I specified `2019` in my query?
The `match_date` column is saved as

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause of your query is parsed as:

```
SELECT *
FROM matches
WHERE home_player = 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' OR
      (away_player = 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' AND strftime('%Y', date(match_date)) = '2019' AND competition = '%')
```

Presumably you intend:

```
WHERE (home_player = 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' OR away_player = 'Jeffrey de Zwaan') AND
      strftime('%Y', date(match_date)) = '2019' AND
      competition = '%'
```

This could be further simplified to:

```
WHERE 'Jeffrey de Zwaan' IN (home_player, away_player) AND
      strftime('%Y', date(match_date)) = '2019' AND
      competition = '%'
```

Comment: I thought the same. Is it generally so that (first?) `OR` makes the rest a block by itself ? I tried to find some rules for this.

Comment: @MyICQ . . . The SQLite documentation covers the precedence of operators (https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), but it is pretty much the same in all databases.